# New identity for sum over Young diagram of symmetric group?

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-groups, partitions

Consider the next identity
$$
\sum_{\tau \vdash r} d^2 (\tau ) \! \prod_{i = -(r-1)}^{r-1} \! \! \left(  N+i  \right)^{t_i^r} =\sum_{\tau \vdash r} d^2 (\tau ) \prod_{i = 1}^{r}  \Gamma [N + \tau_i - i +1]= r! \, N^{r} 
$$
where $d(\tau)$ is dimension of representation  of a permutation group $S_r$  and $\tau =(\tau_1,...,\tau_{l(\tau)})$ is a partition of $\tau \vdash r$,  some power`s coefficients $t_i^r$ dictated by corresponding Young diagram.

I don`t have  proof or combinatorial meaning of this fact.

For example $r=2$
$$
N(N+1)+(N-1)N= 2! N^2  \ ,
$$
for $r=3$
$$
N(N+1)(N+2)+2^2(N-1)N(N+1)+(N-2)(N-1)N= 3! N^3 \ ,
$$
for $r=4$ we have less trivial case
$$
N(N+1)(N+2)(N+3)+3^2(N-1)N(N+1)(N+2)+ 2^2(N-1)N^2(N+1)+3^2(N-2)(N-1)N(N+1)+(N-3)(N-2)(N-1)N = 4!\, N^4
$$
and so on.

The structure of the summand in brackets  is cleared by the illustration of the Young diagram for partition  $(3,2,2)$ that belongs to $r=7$ case.

[image]

Even don`t clear, is this identity obvious.
Is this a known fact at all?

P.S.
Of course, this is more sophisticated modification of known identity
$$
\sum_{\tau \vdash r} d^2 (\tau ) =r!
$$

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312604/syt-and-contents-of-a-partition/312609#312609

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi
 thank you.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi What we could say about another quantity  $\sum_{\tau \vdash r} d^2 (\tau ) \prod_{i = 1}^{r}  \Gamma [N + \tau_i - i +1]/  \Gamma [N + \tau_i - i +1+q]= ?$, where $q$ is integer.  Is there a closed expression?

Comment: What is $\Gamma$?

Comment: $\Gamma$ is Gamma function.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi I created new topic for this subject  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407076/how-to-obtain-explicit-formula-for-this-sum-over-young-diagram?noredirect=1&lq=1