# How to obtain explicit formula for this sum over Young diagram?

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-groups, partitions

Consider the next essence
$$
B_N (r, q) =\sum_{\tau \vdash r} d^2 (\tau ) \prod_{i = 1}^{r} \frac{\Gamma [N + \tau_i - i +1]}{\Gamma [N + \tau_i - i +1+q]}
$$
where $d(\tau)$ is dimension of representation  of a permutation group $S_r$  and $\tau =(\tau_1,...,\tau_{l(\tau)})$ is a partition of $\tau \vdash r$ and $r\leq N$ .

For example, here are the first few coefficients:
\begin{equation}
B_N(0,q) \ = \ B_N(r,0) \ = \  1  \ ,
\label{QSUN_r0}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
B_N(1,q) \ = \ \frac{1}{\Delta_1}   \ ,
\label{QSUN_r1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
B_N(2,q) \ = \ \frac{1}{\Delta_2}[N^2 y-1]  \ ,
\label{QSUN_r2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
B_N(3,q) \ = \ \frac{1}{\Delta_3}[N^4 y^2 -N^2(3 y+2)+4]  \ ,
\label{QSUN_r3}
\end{equation}
and  \begin{eqnarray}
 &&\Delta_r \ = \ y^{p_0} (N^2 y^2-1)^{p_1} ...(N^2 y^2 - (r-1)^2)^{p_{r-1}} \ ,
\end{eqnarray}
where
\begin{equation}
 p_m^r \equiv p_m = \left[ \frac{\sqrt{4 r + m^2} - m}{2} \right], \ \ \  y = 1+ q/N
\end{equation}

Also it is known  result for $q=1$
\begin{equation}
B_N(r,1) \ = \ \frac{r! N!}{(r+N)!} \ L_r^{(N)}(1) \ ,
\label{BSUN_q1}
\end{equation}
where $L_r^{(N)}(x)$ is the generalized Laguerre polynomial.

Early, I found general representation of this object in the limit $N \to \infty $.

I`m interesting in explicit formula or any connection to known function or objects.

More simple case here:
[New identity for sum over Young diagram of symmetric group?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406762/new-identity-for-sum-over-young-diagram-of-symmetric-group) , [SYT and contents of a partition](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312604/syt-and-contents-of-a-partition/312609#312609)